# How Microsoft Compatability Telemetry can be stopped?

Tags: windows-10, services, telemetry

I tried to use this commands:
stop-service diagtrack
set-service diagtrack -startuptype disabled

And tried to create record AllowTelemetry with 0 value here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection

Both ways doesn't work, it starts again after boot.

Comment: The simplest way to disable telemetry is to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise.  The group policy your attempting to set, by changing that registry key, is ignored on Professional and Home versions of Windows 10.  telemetry cannot be fully disabled on Home and Professional version of Windows 10 (1511, 1607 and 1703)

Comment: The majority of the telemetry can be controlled in 1703 by the way

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1719694.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Windows 10 Pro, and I have found a nice way to disable it, the way that I do it is deleting CompatTelRunner.exe in System32, this way, it won't start.
It will come back with a Windows Update but you simply delete it again.
To delete it you must take the privilage of it.

Comment: This does not provide a solution

Comment: @yass why ? This is a way to stop Telemetry. Yes, periodically should be repeated, but good enough.

Comment: Rename it, don't delete it. If something that relies on that executable existing breaks, you won't be able to fix it unless you get a clean copy of the file again. Renaming it will keep the file and its existing permissions, and it still won't run since it doesn't have the same name anymore.