# How to delete the folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs" and stop Windows from piling up garbage on my SSD?

Tags: windows-10, services, telemetry

There are many mentions of this folder on the web, it's clear that it relates to Windows 10 telemetry, and many people want to get rid of this folder (it's 30 GB on my C: drive at the moment, and it accounts for most of the mysterious loss of free space over time). However, all the solutions I could find are outdated as they suggest disabling the DiagTrack service which no longer exists.

I'm running Win 10 Pro x64 2004. How can I at least delete this folder (inaccessible to regular file managers), and preferably - stop it from being regenerated?

P. S. I was able (to my surprise) to simply delete this folder with `rmdir /S` from Administrator command prompt, but the real question is how to stop it from regenerating.

Comment: (1) In which subfolder are the files inside `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs`? (2) Could you post online one example `.etl` file? (3) Run [EventLogChannelsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/event_log_channels_view.html) and see if you can find `C:\ProgramData` under "Full Path" (sort by click on column), and if it's there then right-click it and select Disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in your case Windows Telemetry is running wild.
The following is a list of all the methods I know to stop telemetry.
Reboot after applying.

**Change Privacy Settings**

- Open *Settings > Privacy > General*
- Toggle all options to Off
- Select on the left "Diagnostic and Feedback"
- Select on top the option saying "Required diagnostic data"
- Toggle "Tailored experience" to Off

**Disable Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry**

Run Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and enter the following commands:

```
sc stop DiagTrack
sc config DiagTrack start= disabled
sc stop dmwappushservice
sc config dmwappushservice start= disabled
echo "" > C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Diagnosis\\ETLLogs\\AutoLogger\\AutoLogger-Diagtrack-Listener.etl
reg add "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DataCollection" /v AllowTelemetry /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

**Disable From The Local Policy Editor**

- Run the Local Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to the following location:
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview Builds*
- Locate and double-click on the "Allow telemetry" option
- Change its status to Disabled
- Click on OK to save the changes

**Use Task Scheduler to disable CompatTelRunner.exe process**

- Run Task Scheduler
- Expand the following folders:
  Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Application Experience
- Right-click "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" and select "Disable"
- Confirm to complete the process

Comment: You could be right, I did run one or two telemetry blocking scripts from Github. I would never have thought they'd go as far as to completely delete service, I agree it's too much. And thank you for pointing me to the Repair Install option, I've never done that before and would like to try it because I have a very annoying problem with this system: an update fails to install and it gives me grief regularly.

Comment: Thank you for this! But I'm wondering what the command echo "" > C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Diagnosis\\ETLLogs\\AutoLogger\\AutoLogger-Diagtrack-Listener.etl is supposed to do? This folder is currently empty. Thank you

Comment: @Copperplate: This file contains the collected telemetry data. The `echo` command truncates it to a minimal size.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for clarifying. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Open [`cmd` *as administrator*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator).
Then run :
<sup>1</sup>

```
net stop DiagTrack & sc config DiagTrack start= disabled
```

Expect a response like :

```
The Connected User Experiences and Telemetry service was stopped successfully.
```

or :

```
The Connected User Experiences and Telemetry service is not started.
```

and :

```
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

You might have to re-run this every time
[Windows Update installs a new build version](https://www.windowscentral.com/using-windows-update-install-new-builds-windows-10-technical-preview).

##### About DiagTrack

> However, all the solutions I could find are outdated as they suggest
> disabling the DiagTrack service which no longer exists.

With all due respect, I think you are wrong. I am currently on
version 21H2 (build 19044), and DiagTrack was definitely *running*
after I recently ran Windows Update.
(I have since disabled it.)

[image: Henke Windows specifications, April 2022.]

But I don't blame you for not finding it.
Microsoft once [renamed](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/11/19/microsoft-rena-and-telemetry/) it from 'Diagnostics Tracking Service' to 'Connected User Experiences and Telemetry'.
Keeping the name unchanged over the years would have made the life for us – their paying customers – much too easy?

Hit <kbd>Win ⊞</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, paste `services.msc` and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Sort by name and look for *Connected User Experiences and Telemetry*
and double-click that service.

Instead of running the command above, you can achieve the exact same
thing as follows.

Where it says *Service status: Running*, click **Stop**.
Then where it says *Startup type: Automatic*, change to **Disabled**.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and then <kbd>F5</kbd>.

As you can see, the **DiagTrack** service is sadly still around.
<sup>2</sup>

[image: Henke DiagTrack service settings, April 2022.]

#### References

- [Open `cmd` *as administrator*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator)
- [Windows Update installs a new build version](https://www.windowscentral.com/using-windows-update-install-new-builds-windows-10-technical-preview)
- [Windows 10 telemetry secrets](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-telemetry-secrets/) article on ZDNET.
- [You are not alone with this problem.](https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/4932793)

---

<sup>1</sup> *Never, ever* run `sc delete`!

<sup>2</sup>
I wish Microsoft would get rid of it, but I don't think they will.

Comment: This was the correct answer a while ago, but as I've literally written in my question, the DiagTrack service no longer exists in more recent builds of Windows 10.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This folder is filled by Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry (`CompatTelRunner.exe`), it is started by a scheduled task, the task is located at \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\ and its name is "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser", however there are three other tasks there, so you might disable them all.

This is a PowerShell one-liner that does the job, note you need Administrator Privileges to do so.

```
"Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser","PcaPatchDbTask","ProgramDataUpdater","StartupAppTask" | %{ Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\" -TaskName $_ | Out-Null }
```

If these commands give you errors, then you need run these commands with `TrustedInstaller` privileges, you can use either NSudo or PsExec.

Comment: In addition to this answer, if you have another (non-ssd) drive attached, you can junction a folder from it to the SSD drive and save the wear and tear on your SSD drive.